# How to call a wizard in write function Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In write function of  'stock.move' model , I want t return a wizard if some conditions, but that not work.

Here is my code:

```
 def write(self, vals):

        # Handle the write on the initial demand by updating the reserved quantity and logging
        # messages according to the state of the stock.move records.
        receipt_moves_to_reassign = self.env['stock.move']
        if 'product_uom_qty' in vals:
            for move in self.filtered(lambda m: m.state not in ('done', 'draft') and m.picking_id):
                if float_compare(vals['product_uom_qty'], move.product_uom_qty,
                                 precision_rounding=move.product_uom.rounding):
                    self.env['stock.move.line']._log_message(move.picking_id, move, 'stock.track_move_template', vals)
            if self.env.context.get('do_not_unreserve') is None:
                move_to_unreserve = self.filtered(
                    lambda m: m.state not in ['draft', 'done', 'cancel'] and float_compare(m.reserved_availability,
                                                                                           vals.get('product_uom_qty'),
                                                                                           precision_rounding=m.product_uom.rounding) == 1
                )
                move_to_unreserve._do_unreserve()
                (self - move_to_unreserve).filtered(lambda m: m.state == 'assigned').write(
                    {'state': 'partially_available'})
                # When editing the initial demand, directly run again action assign on receipt moves.
                receipt_moves_to_reassign |= move_to_unreserve.filtered(lambda m: m.location_id.usage == 'supplier')
                receipt_moves_to_reassign |= (self - move_to_unreserve).filtered(
                    lambda m: m.location_id.usage == 'supplier' and m.state in ('partially_available', 'assigned'))
        if 'date_deadline' in vals:
            self._set_date_deadline(vals.get('date_deadline'))
        res = super(StockMove, self).write(vals)
        if 'move_line_nosuggest_ids' in vals:
            done_qty = vals['move_line_nosuggest_ids'][0][2]['qty_done']
            for rec in self:
                if rec.product_uom_qty < done_qty:
                    return self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("my_module.action_test")


        if receipt_moves_to_reassign:
            receipt_moves_to_reassign._action_assign()
        return res
```

What's wrong please ?
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but isn't possible in write doing action (Open wizard). You can do it with JS .

Comment: @jo541, Is it possible to do it in onchange function ? _inherit = "stock.move.line" @api.onchange('qty_done') def onchange_qty_done(self): action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("my_module.action_test") return action

Comment: Write and onchange isn't the same thing. Write will save data in database. Onchange is a JS interaction.. Nothing is save is DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can not open wizard or any action from write. if you see write function's return type it's a Boolean

*Thumb rule: you can not return action until browser request/call for it*

The workaround you could try is, raise ValidationError or UserError with a message.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in onchange function ?                             _inherit = "stock.move.line"

    @api.onchange('qty_done')
    def onchange_qty_done(self):
        action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("my_module.action_test")
        return action

Comment: @K.ju not even from onchange. cycle should start either from call() or do_action() at JavaScript side. for example buttons on the top of view inside headers